# Extracting text information from an HTML file in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

In a piece of code that I'm writing I am required to get some information from a webpage. This information will vary depending on the user that is logged in.

I'm trying to get the two pieces of information labeled *name here* and *id number here* in the code below.

```
<tr> 
  <td align="right"><b><label for="name" id="lblname">Name:</label></b> &nbsp;</td> 
  <td>*name here*</td> 
  <td align="right"><b><label for="ident" id="lblident">Local ID</label>:</b> &nbsp;</td> 
  <td>*id number here*</td> 
</tr>
```

The best that I've been able to accomplish so far is printing the Element "name from the code below.

```
Element name = information.getElementById("lblname");
```

All it outputs is this portion of the code:

```
<label for="name" id="lblname">Name:</label>
```

What would I need to do to define the *name here* portion of the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You may probably use regular expression to extract what you want after getting `<tr> </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) of Jsoup to extract the exact elements you need, for example:

```
// select the "name" <td>
Element name = doc.select("td:has(label#lblname) + td").first();

// select the "id" <td>
Element id = doc.select("td:has(label#lblident) + td").first();

// print out the text 
System.out.println(name.text());
System.out.println(id.text());
```

Using your example, the output will be:

```
*name here*
*id number here*
```